# Why am I getting this PostgreSQL error on this join...?

Tags: postgresql

trying to comment out the join fields with this PostgreSQL statement:

```
select 
        veh."Truck Name",
        veh."Truck Type",
        veh.office,
        --off.address, 
        --off.city, 
        --off.state, 
        --off.zipcode 
    from 
        vehicles veh
        --join offices off on veh.office = off.office 
    order by
        veh.office asc;
```

I get the following error:
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "from"
  Position: 180

I want to be able to remove the -- indicators and run the report

Comment: remove the `,` after `veh.office,`

Comment: `veh.office,` <-- remove the dangling comma.  Voting to close as a typo question.

Answer (score 2):

just remove comma after veh.office

```
  select 
    veh."Truck Name",
    veh."Truck Type",
    veh.office
    --off.address, 
    --off.city, 
    --off.state, 
    --off.zipcode 
from 
    vehicles veh
    --join offices off on veh.office = off.office 
order by
    veh.office asc;
```

Comment: Answering typo questions is off topic for this site.  Just vote to close and move on.

Comment: Thanks so much. Sorry for the elementary question.